# Favicon doesn't load for safari

Tags: html, css, safari, favicon

I am a beginner in HTML and I was trying to set favicon for my webpage. It works for chrome with no problem but Safari doesn't show me the favicon.
This is how I'm linking the favicon in the head section:
`<link rel="icon" href="jesse.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

I tried a bunch of different things like transforming the jpg image to an ico icon file and resizing the image and editing the code such it includes `apple-touch-icon` instead of just `icon`
Something like this:
`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="jesse.ico" type="image/x-apple-touch-icon">`
But even this would not work for Safari. I don't understand why.

Comment: Could be that your web page has been cached in safari. If you previously visited the page before you added the icon atleast. If so, try clearing your cache first.